# Bernstein polynomial for functions

Tags: polynomials, summation, proof-writing

Let $B_n(f)$ be the nth Bernstein Polynomial for $f\in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$ and let $F(x) = x$. 
Show that $B_n(F)(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{n}F(\frac{i}{n}) {n \choose i} x^i (1-x)^{n-i} = F(x)$.

I began like this $B_n(F)(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{n}F(\frac{i}{n}) {n \choose i} x^i (1-x)^{n-i} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{i}{n}{n \choose i} x^i (1-x)^{n-i}= \sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(n-1)!}{(i-1)!(n-i)!} x^i (1-x)^{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n-1 \choose i-1} x^i (1-x)^{n-i}$.

But now I don't know how to finish this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $B_n(F)(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\ \binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$ and the following  implications are verified $$\frac{k}{n}\ \binom{n}{k}=\frac{k}{n}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)![(n-1)-(k-1)]!}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$ $$\Rightarrow B_n(F)(x)=x\sum_{k=1}^n\ \binom{n-1}{k-1}x^{k-1}(1-x)^{(n-1)-(k-1)}$$ $$=x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ \binom{n-1}{k}x^{k}(1-x)^{(n-1)-k}=x(x+(1-x))^{n-1}=x.$$ So, $B_n(F)(x)=x.$

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to show that $B_n(x^2) = (1 - \frac{1}{n})x^2 + \frac{1}{n}F$?

Comment: Yes, have a look at http://fernandorevilla.es/blog/2018/04/12/polinomios-de-bernstein/ (problem 2). It is in Spanish but surely there is no problem for you to follow the outline.

Comment: Shouldn't the first sum used be from $k=0$ to $n$? If so, how does this change the proof?