# Bernstein polynomial for $f(x)=x$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to compute the Bernstein Polynomial for $f(x)=x$. I found a solution via this website but the solution used an incorrect definition. I commented on the question, but no one responded. So, I have asked the question myself.

I haven't got very far. I am aware of the trick that $\frac{p}{n}{n\choose p}={{n-1}\choose{p-1}}.$

[Note: I used $x\choose y$ to denote $x$ choose $y$, I am unsure about the correct latex for it.]

Comment: $\binom{x}{y}$ is "\binom{x}{y}". It would be useful to see the mentioned solution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815888/bernstein-polynomial-for-functions

Comment: They sum from k=1 not 0. Also am unsure about their last step in the solution

Comment: When $k=0$, $k/n=0$ and so $\sum_{k=0}^n\ldots=\sum_{k=1}^n\ldots$.

Comment: Also the last step is due to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $1 = (1-x+x)^m = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} x^k (1-x)^{m-k}$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
B_n(f)(x) &=& \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f({k \over n}) x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^n  \binom{n}{k} {k \over n} x^k (1-x)^{n-k} \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^n  \binom{n-1}{k-1}  x^{k+1} (1-x)^{n-k} \\
&=& x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \binom{n-1}{k}  x^k (1-x)^{n-1-k} \\
&=& x \\
\end{eqnarray}